# How can I use two keyboards and two mice to control two different programs on the same computer as if they were on separated machines?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I need to run two programs, each on a different display ( primary and secondary display ) on the same windows 7 machine. How can I use two USB keyboards and two mice to control these two programs independently ? For example, use one keyboard and mouse to control a software on the first display and another keyboard and mouse to control another program running on a secondary display, like they were two different computers, without confusing them ? I mean, a specific keyboard and mouse would never assume it´s on the other software ? Can this be possible ? I thought about installing a virtual machine, but for what I know, we can´t dedicate a keyboard and a mouse specifically to a VM, can we ?

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to your last question:  yes, that is possible. You can do a USB device passthrough to your guest. If you passthrough one set of keyboard and mouse they will not affect the host at all.

Comment: Humm, the question now is how to do a USB device passthrough vmware. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: It is very simple to do in Virtualbox. I don't use VMWare as much so right off the top of my head I don't know the steps to accomplish it there.